# Failed dismiss 2 view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift4

I have 3 ViewController : LoginViewController, CheckinViewController, & ProfileViewController

The flow is :
LoginVC --> CheckinVC --> ProfileVC

What i need is:
I want to dismiss "ProfileVC" & "CheckinVC" when click logout button in "ProfileVC" then go back to the "LoginVC"

#### LoginVC.swift

```
let checkinViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CheckinViewController") as! CheckinViewController                    
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(checkinViewController, animated: true)
JustHUD.shared.hide()
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

#### CheckinVC.swift

```
if let profileView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") {
        profileView.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        profileView.definesPresentationContext = true
        profileView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext;
        //            profileView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.8)
        profileView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        profileView.view.isOpaque = false
        self.present(profileView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is i'm trying to do

#### ProfileVC.swift

```
@IBAction func clickLogout(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
        print("ProfileView : dismiss completed")

        let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
            print("SUCCESS")
        })

    })
}
```

[image: ProblemDismiss]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you need to do an `Unwind Segue` so you can go back in your `LoginVC`. 
Follow these simple four steps to create `Unwind segues`:

1. In the view controller you are trying to go back to, `LoginVC` in your example, write this code:

   ```
   @IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }
   ```

> ( Remember: It’s important to insert this method in the view
>   controller you are trying to go back TO! )

1. In the `Storyboard`, go to the screen you’re trying to unwind from ( ProfileVC in our case ), and control + drag the `viewController` icon to the Exit icon located on top.

[image: exit]
 3. Go to the document outline of the selected `viewController` in the `Storyboard`, select `the unwind segue` as shown below.

[image: storyboard]

Now, go to the `Attributes Inspector` in the `Utilities Pane` and name the identifier of the unwind segue.

[image: identity inspector]

4. Finally, write this code where you want the unwind segue action to be triggered, `ProfileVC` in our case.

   ```
    @IBAction func clickLogout(_ sender: Any) {
           UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
             UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
               performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToVC1", sender: self)
    }
   ```

For more information check [Create Unwind Segues](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f)

Comment: I cant do ctrl + drag from "Icon vc" to "Icon exit", something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

While Enea Dume's solution is correct if you want to use storyboards, here is the explanation of the problem, and the solution if you want to do it in code like you have been so far.

**The Issue**

If we focus on the self.dismiss calls in the logoutFunction in ProfileVC, this is what happens.

The first time you call self.dismiss, ProfileVC will dismiss itself and be removed from the view stack.

In the completion delegate, you are pushing a new LoginVC to a navigation controller. However, the CheckIN VC is presented over the navigation controller so you can't see anything happen.

The second call to self.dismiss does nothing as ProfileVC is not presenting any other view controllers and it is not in the stack any longer.

**The Solution**

You need to keep a reference to LoginVC that presented the CheckInVC. If you call "reference to LoginVC".dismiss, it will dismiss the view controllers above it in the stack and take you back to the login view controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the class CheckinVC.swift, in the function viewDidAppear, check if the user is still active or not based on the session that you are maintaining and the pop to login view controller accordingly. If user status is logged out, then it will go to login view controller. Else it will work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying to dismiss twice ProfileVC but what you actually need is to dismiss it and then pop CheckinVC.

Also after dismissing a view controller it no longer has a reference to the NavigationController so you need a reference to it in a temporal variable.

Change ProfileVC like this:

```
@IBAction func clickLogout(_ sender: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    let navigationController = self.navigationController
    let loginViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
        print("ProfileView : dismiss completed")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    })
}
```